# Genero un div con Javascript, se muestra medio segundo y desaparece solo

Tags: javascript, html

Estaba haciendo esto para practicar, venía todo bien, de hecho funcionaba hasta que en los inputs donde uno ingresa la cancion, artista y tab, pongo el atributo autocomplete="off", pero lo saqué (como pueden ver en el código abajo) y sigue sin funcionar, el problema es que aparece el nuevo div, perfectamente como lo quiero, pero desaparece solo: inspecciono con las herramientas del navegador y efectivamente no está presente de ninguna manera.
Por otro lado, no aparecen mensajes de error.

```js
const btnAddItem= document.getElementById('btn-add'),
      artist= document.getElementById('input-artist'),
      song=document.getElementById('input-song'),
      modal=document.querySelector('.modal-background'),
      btnAddSong=document.getElementById('btn-add_song'),
      tab=document.getElementById('input-tabs'),
      form=document.getElementById('form');

btnAddItem.addEventListener('click',()=>{
    var newSong= song.value;
    var newArtist=artist.value;
    var newTab= tab.value;
    var newItem=document.createElement("DIV");
    newItem.innerHTML=`
    <div class="item">
        <h3 class="song">${newSong}</h3>
        <h3 class="artist">${newArtist}</h3>
        <a class="link" href="${newTab}" target="_blank" ><h3>TABS</h3></a><input type="range" />
    </div>`;
    
    document.body.appendChild(newItem);
    
    modal.style.display="none";

    form.reset();
});

btnAddSong.addEventListener('click',function(){

    modal.style.display="flex";
    
});
```

```html
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Songs chart</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text/css" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="title-container">
      <h3>CHART</h3>
      <button id="btn-add_song">Add</button>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-background">
      <div class="modal">
        <form id="form">
          <input type="text" id="input-song" placeholder="Song" value="" />
          <input type="text" id="input-artist" placeholder="Artist" value="" />
          <input
            type="text"
            id="input-tabs"
            placeholder="Link for TABS"
            value=""
          />
          <button id="btn-add">ADD</button>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
  <script src="main.js"></script>
</html>
```

Comment: Si no quieres que se ejecute el form submit cuando haces click en "ADD", puedes tambien solo agregar el atributo type="button" al elemento button en el HTML, en un formulario, los botones, si no les declaras el tipo tendran por defecto el type="submit" que es el que te envia el formulario y te limpia tu resultado

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Tendrías que agregar [**`e.preventDefault()`**](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_preventdefault.asp) para evitar que se recargue la página al enviar el formulario: o sea, cuando haces clic en el botón *add*, se crea un nuevo elemento `DIV`, y al no usar `preventDefault()`, el formulario se envía y se recarga la página, eliminando el nuevo elemento que se agregó. Tu código vendría a ser el siguiente:

```js
const btnAddItem = document.getElementById('btn-add'),
  artist = document.getElementById('input-artist'),
  song = document.getElementById('input-song'),
  modal = document.querySelector('.modal-background'),
  btnAddSong = document.getElementById('btn-add_song'),
  tab = document.getElementById('input-tabs'),
  form = document.getElementById('form');

btnAddItem.addEventListener('click', e => {
  var newSong = song.value;
  var newArtist = artist.value;
  var newTab = tab.value;
  var newItem = document.createElement('DIV');
  newItem.innerHTML = `
    <div class="item">
        <h3 class="song">${newSong}</h3>
        <h3 class="artist">${newArtist}</h3>
        <a class="link" href="${newTab}" target="_blank" ><h3>TABS</h3></a><input type="range" />
    </div>`;

  document.body.appendChild(newItem);

  modal.style.display = 'none';

  form.reset();
  e.preventDefault();
});

btnAddSong.addEventListener('click', function () {
  modal.style.display = 'flex';
});
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="title-container">
    <h3>CHART</h3>
    <button id="btn-add_song">Add</button>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-background">
    <div class="modal">
      <form id="form">
        <input type="text" id="input-song" placeholder="Song" value="" />
        <input type="text" id="input-artist" placeholder="Artist" value="" />
        <input
            type="text"
            id="input-tabs"
            placeholder="Link for TABS"
            value=""
          />
        <button id="btn-add">ADD</button>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Muchísimas gracias a ambos!! Funcionan ambas opciones.